# Does Algebraic Structure (Set with $k$-ary Operation) Imply Each of its $k$ Domains and Codomain are Equal?

Tags: abstract-algebra

An [operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_(mathematics)), in the most general sense, is a function which takes a cartesian product $S_1 \times S_2 \times \cdots \times S_k$ as its domain and another set $T$ as its codomain. In general, each of the $k$ sets can be different.

However, now let's talk about algebraic structures. Wikipedia (a bit carelessly) defines an [Algebraic Structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_structure) as a set $S$ with one or more finitary operations "defined on it". What's unclear about this definition is what is meant by "defined on it".

Here is my question: does this definition of an algebraic structure $(S,*)$, where $*:S_1 \times S_2 \times \cdots \times S_k \to T$, implicitly imply that $S_1=S_2=\cdots=S_k$? Also, does it imply that $T=S$? If so, this should be explicitly said, because an "operation" in the general sense does not imply this. Maybe we can edit the Wikipedia page to be more clear.

Also, what word or term would one use to distinguish between an operation $*:S_1 \times S_2 \times \cdots \times S_k \to T$ which takes $S_1=S_2=\cdots=S_k=T$ and one which does not?

Thank you!

Comment: *"Often, use of the term operation implies that the domain of the function is a power of the codomain, although this is by no means universal, as in the example of multiplying a vector by a scalar."* - from the first wikipedia article that you linked to.

Comment: I saw that. However that does not clear up which case is meant in the definition of an Algebraic Structure. Also, what word or term would one use to distinguish between an operation $*:S_1 \times S_2 \times \cdots \times S_k \to T$ which takes $S_1=S_2=\cdots=S_k=T$ and one which does not?

Comment: An algebraic structure is a tuple of the form $(S,f_i)_{i\in I}$ for some set $I$. Associated to each $i\in I$ there is a natural number $n_i$ (the *arity* of $f_i$) such that $f_i:S^{n_i}\to S$. Here, $I$ could be empty (although the link you give requires that it is not), and some of the $n_i$ could be $0$ (in which case we could identify $f_i$ with the element of $S$ that $f_i$ "selects").

Comment: Ah, okay. Thank you for your answer. So it seems to be that in the context of Algebraic Structure, the domain of an $f_i$ operation is some *power* of $S$, not an arbitrary Cartesian product of (different) sets of length $n_i$. Would that be correct? Feel free to repost this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An algebraic structure is a tuple of the form $(S,f_i)_{i\in I}$ for some set $I$. Associated to each $i\in I$ there is a natural number $n_i$ (the *arity* of $f_i$) such that $f_i:S^{n_i}\to S$; that is, the domain of $f_i$ is a finite power of $S$ rather than a Cartesian product of perhaps different sets. Note that the codomain of $f_i$ is also required to be $S$. Here, $I$ could be empty (although the link you give requires that it is not), and some of the $n_i$ could be $0$ (in which case we could identify $f_i$ with the element of $S$ that $f_i$ "selects").

Although algebraic structures are ubiquitous in mathematics, *universal algebra* is the area that studies them (not quite abstract algebra, as suggested in the link you gave).

Sometimes, particularly in set theory, one talks of "algebras" to mean structures $(S,f_i)_{i\in I}$ where, for all $i\in I$, $f_i:S^{<\mathbb N}\to S$. Here, $S^{<\mathbb N}$ is the set of finite tuples of elements of $S$. But note that each $f_i$ can be identified with countably many functions $f_{i,n}$, where $f_{i,n}:S^n\to S$ is simply $f_i\upharpoonright S^n$, so that this version is really just a particular case (in disguise) of the general notion.

Finally, note that not all structures studied in mathematics are algebraic structures. For instance, metric spaces are pairs $(M,d)$ where $d:M\times M\to \mathbb R$, even if $\mathbb R$ and $M$ have nothing in common as sets.

Comment: Thank you for the awesome answer. I have a couple questions for clarification. I was with you until $f_i\upharpoonright S^n$; what does this mean? Secondly, does each $f_i$ need to operate on cartesian powers of the same arity? Lastly, I was wondering what one calls the number of operations in an algebraic structure -- that is, whereas $n_i$ denotes the _arity_ of $f$ in the algebraic structure, the cardinality of $I$ is called the algebraic structure's (_term goes here_)?

Comment: And thanks again for the extra information in your answer. I didn't realize there were other kinds of structures other than algebraic structures. I was even mistakenly thinking of a metric space as an algebraic structure -- you must have known that somehow. If not an _algebraic_ structure, what kind of structure would you call a metric space $(M,d)$, or even a topological space $(S,\tau)$? Thanks!

Comment: In paragraph $3$, the function $f_i$ takes as arguments all finite tuples of elements of $S$, so $f_i(\emptyset)$ is defined, as is $f_i(a)$ for each $a\in S$, and $f_i(a,b)$ for each $a,b\in S$, etc. The function $f_{i,3}$ for example, has domain $S^3$, and is defined by $f_{i,3}(a,b,c)=f_i(a,b,c)$. That is, $f_{i,3}$ is the *restriction* of $f_i$ to the set $S^3$ of triples of elements of $S$. The notation $g\upharpoonright A$ denotes the function that results from restricting $g$ to domain $A$. So, in this case, $f_{i,3}=f_i\upharpoonright S^3$. Similarly for all other $n$ in place of $3$.

Comment: (But note that the domain of a function in an algebraic structure is always a finite power of $S$, while here the domain of $f_i$ is $S^{<\mathbb N}=\bigcup_n S^n$, a different thing altogether.)

Comment: We usually denote by $\aleph_0$ the size of the natural numbers. I would not call $|I|$ anything special, but the *larger* of $|I|$ and $\aleph_0$ is usually called the *size of the language*. If $|I|$ is finite, all I would say that the structure has finite language. This refers to the *first order language* that comes associated to the structure, whose *vocabulary* or [*signature*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_%28logic%29) would have non-logical function symbols $\dot f_i$ for each $i\in I$.

Comment: The Wikipedia entry on algebraic structures calls *hybrid* those structures that are not purely algebraic (such as metric or topological spaces). I do not know whether other common terms are used as well to denote them.